Can I improve my code to extract permutation cycles from a (n,2) matrix?
I've written a routine to extract permutation cycles from a (n,2) matrix, each row giving the format $a\to b$ which represents the first two elements in some $k$ cycle.  If $a\to a$, it's a $1$-cycle.  If $a\to d$ and then the row $d\to a$ then this is a $2$-cycle and so forth.  Not sure how to precisely word this in terms of Group Theory.
Consider a (10,2) array with such data:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & 7 \\
 3 & 10 \\
 4 & 3 \\
 5 & 5 \\
 6 & 8 \\
 7 & 2 \\
 8 & 6 \\
 9 & 4 \\
 10 & 9 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The first row is $(1,1)$ so this is a $1$-cycle,  next have $(2,7)$ which links to $(7,2)$ giving a $2$-cycle.  Next is $(3,10)$ linking to $(10,9)$ to $(9,4)$ and $(4,3)$ giving a $4$-cycle,  then the $1$-cycle $(5,5)$, then the $2$-cycle $(6,8)$ to $(8,6)$.
The following is my code and I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to extract permutation cycles from such an array?
     array = {{1, 1}, {2, 7}, {3, 10}, {4, 3}, {5, 5}, {6, 8}, {7, 2}, {8,
        6}, {9, 4}, {10, 9}}
    arraySize = Length@array;
    monoSave = {};
    index = 0;
    While[Length@array > 0 && index < 20,
      index++;
      base = array[[1, 1]];
      next = array[[1, 2]];
      save = {{1}};
      pos = 1;
      monodromy = {base};
      monodromy = {};
      While[base != next && index < 20,
       index++;
       pos = Position[array[[All, 1]], x_ /; x == next][[1, 1]];
       AppendTo[save, {pos}];
       next = array[[pos, 2]];
       ];
      AppendTo[monodromy, array[[Flatten@save]]];
      array = Delete[array, save];
      AppendTo[monoSave, monodromy];
      ];
    
    finalCycles = #[[All, 1]] & /@ (Flatten[monoSave, 1])
    If[Sort[Flatten@finalCycles] != Range[arraySize],
      Print["group is not a permutation"];
      ,
      Print["group is a permutation"];
      ];

(* {{1}, {2, 7}, {3, 10, 9, 4}, {5}, {6, 8}} *)


Given your permutation as permutation of {1,2,3,...} in the form of a vector like:
perm = {1, 7, 10, 3, 5, 8, 2, 6, 4, 9}

you can get all cycles by:
PermutationCycles[perm]

(* Cycles[{{2, 7}, {3, 10, 9, 4}, {6, 8}}] *)

This is the same permutation written as cycles.
Note that a fixpoint (e.g. 1) is not considered a cycle.

Ok, thanks Daniel!  Lot easier than mine.  And I pick up the $1$ cycles via Complement[Range[n],Flatten@PermutationCycles[perm][[1]]]
